# Python tkinter Help - button accessing other functions

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code I have 3 separate buttons being made, two are only to be accessed after the first one is pushed. For some reason when I run the code and press the 'Place' button, my 'winClicked' and 'loseClicked' functions are accessed even though they are not supposed to until the win/lose butting are pushed. What do I need to fix so that 'winClicked' and 'loseClicked' only run when the buttons are pushed?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


# Window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("750x500")
window.configure(background='gray')
window.title("Fantasy Betting Log")

# Bank
bank = 100
bankLbl = Label(window, text="Bank: " + str(bank))
bankLbl.place(x=0, y=0)



# Functions
def win(wager, odds):
    if int(odds) > 0:
        return float(wager) * float(odds) / 100
    if int(odds) < 0:
        return float(wager) * 100 / abs(float(odds))

def winClicked(name, wager, odds):
    log.insert(INSERT,'WIN - ' + name + ' won you ' + str(win(wager, odds)))
    log.insert(END, "$ \n")


def loseClicked(name, wager):
    log.insert(INSERT,'LOSS - ' + name + ' lost you ' + str(wager))
    log.insert(END, "$ \n")


counter = 0
def newLiveBet(name, wager, odds):
    global counter
    liveBet = Label(window, text= name + " - Wager: " + wager + ", Odds: " + odds)
    liveBet.place(x=10, y=(300 + (30 * counter)))
    winButton = Button(window, text="Win", width=3, bg="white", fg="green", command=winClicked(name,wager, odds))
    winButton.place(x= 400, y = (300 + (30 * counter)))
    loseButton = Button(window, text="Lose", width=3, bg="white", fg="red", command=loseClicked(name, wager))
    loseButton.place(x= 450, y = (300 + (30 * counter)))
    counter += 1

def placeClicked():
    name = betName.get()
    wager = wagerAmt.get()
    odds = oddsAmt.get()
    betName.delete(0, END)
    wagerAmt.delete(0, END)
    oddsAmt.delete(0, END)
    newLiveBet(name, wager, odds)

#Theres more code here but irrelevant to question

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always post **whole error message** with **full traceback** please. You have a function and a variable both named `win`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `win` to be the value of inputted Text:

```
win = input("Did you win your bet? (y/n)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined win in this line

```
    win = input("Did you win your bet? (y/n)")
```

and when you call it

```
    bank += win(wager, odds)
```

It use the string as previously defined `win`, and it is a string (y, n), sot it is not callable as a function.
You should use different variable name.

Comment: Great thanks! I had to change my question a bit. What do you think now?

Comment: That's a completely different error, never edit a whole question like that because other users can't keep track to the questions and answers. Post another thread.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry still new to this